# innerhtml returns undefined but the element exists

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I'm trying to get the innerHTML of an element but it returns undefined.

```
let body = e.target.previousElementSibling.innerHTML;
console.log(body);
```

//returns undefined

However, when I do this:

```
let body = e.target.previousElementSibling;
```

and console log it,

it returns me the element, which is:

```
<p class="card-text"> is the greatest </p>
```

so why is the innerHTML returning undefined?

Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Microposts</title>

  <body>
<div id="posts">


    <div class="card-body 4" data-id="4">
     <h4 class="card-title"> code </h4>
     <p class="card-text"> why is this  </p>
     <i class="fa fa-pencil 4"> </i>
     <i class="fa fa-remove 4 " style="margin-left:30px"> </i>
     </div>



     <div class="card-body 5" data-id="5">
     <h4 class="card-title"> messi </h4>
     <p class="card-text"> is the greatest </p>
     <i class="fa fa-pencil 5"> </i>
     <i class="fa fa-remove 5 " style="margin-left:30px"> </i>
     </div>



     <div class="card-body 6" data-id="6">
     <h4 class="card-title"> Why is the compiler showing following code as incorrect syntax? </h4>
     <p class="card-text"> I dont know </p>
 <i class="fa fa-pencil 5"> </i>
     <i class="fa fa-remove 5 " style="margin-left:30px"> </i>
     </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the JS Code

```
document.querySelector("#posts").addEventListener("click", postUpdate);

function postUpdate(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("fa-pencil")) {
    let id = e.target.parentElement.dataset.id;
    let element = e.target.parentElement;
    let body = e.target.previousElementSibling.innerHTML;
    let title = body.previousElementSibling.innerHTML;

    console.log(body);
  }
}
```

Comment: You'll have to provide more code for context.

Comment: @Pointy I have updated the question now

Comment: Please provide a [mre], with enough of the HTML this code runs on so that others can reproduce the situation. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar) to provide that here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Actually, I'm using modules.. there are 3 separate JS files

Comment: @ohnope nobody knows what your HTML looks like. Nobody can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Can I just post the code in question(because I have 3 separate JS files and without them the code wont work on stack snippets).

Comment: add your html code so that can help you.

Comment: ok I updated the code. Please have a look

Comment: in code `fa-pencil` is missing.

Comment: no that gets added dynamically.. and when i console.log(e.target) and click on fa-pencil. it works and logs fa-pencil

Comment: I've updated the code with how it looks like after dynamically adding the html

Comment: My problem is solved now. I've updated the question with the solution

Comment: add your soliution in answer and then you can accept as answer. user can upvote on this. @ohnope

Comment: ok I've done that. It'll take 2 days to accept the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
let body = e.target.previousElementSibling.innerHTML;
let title = body.previousElementSibling.innerHTML;
```

Do:

```
let body = e.target.previousElementSibling.innerHTML;
let title =e.target.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.innerHTML;
```

Comment: you can accept this answer. You cant upvote on your answer.

Comment: no it says "You can accept your own answer in 2 days"